# Not able to resolve the type of a lambda parameter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, collectors

So I am trying to implement a custom collector but unfortunatelly I am stuck at a pretty interesting problem:

```
@Override
public BiConsumer<Map<LocalDate, List<TripResultDTO>>, TripResultDTO> accumulator() {
    return (acc,elem) -> {
        long departureTime = elem.getOutbound().getDepartureTimeLocal();
        LocalDate departureDate = new LocalDateTime(departureTime).toLocalDate();
        List<TripResultDTO> othersInTheSameDay = acc.getOrDefault(departureDate,new LinkedList<>());
        othersInTheSameDay.add(elem);
        acc.put(departureDate,othersInTheSameDay);
    };
}
```

So in the code above, the compiler cannot resolve any of the methods of the elem object which is of type `TripResultDTO`.

Needless to say the `getOutbound` method is highlighted in red and cannot be resolved. Its quite strange by looking at the intelli sense that the `TripResultsDTO` seems to treated simply as an instance of `Object` rather than `TripResultDTO`. Do you have any idea why that might be happening.

Also any idea for doing what I am doing in a better way are welcome.

Comment: By compiler, which one? What version of javac? Or is it Eclipse, IntelliJ, other?

Comment: javac 1.8.0_60 and IntelliJ 14, I did , no luck with that either

Comment: @Zahari When i comment the content of return block inside `accumulator` method the two argument `acc` and `elem` are correctly resolved to `Map<LocalDate, List<TripResultDTO>>` and `TripResultDTO` types.

Answer (score 0):

So actually that was a pretty noob mistake. What I had done in the signature of the collector was:

```
public class CheapestPerDayCollector <TripResultDTO> implements Collector<TripResultDTO, Map<LocalDate, List<TripResultDTO>>, List<TripResultDTO>> {
```

which actually signified the TripResultsDTO as a generic type rather than the actual class. I rewrote it as :

```
public class CheapestPerDayCollector  implements Collector<TripResultDTO, Map<LocalDate, List<TripResultDTO>>, List<TripResultDTO>> {
```

and now everything works fine.